# Run bot on same server as your own Ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mastering-ethereum

I have been tinkering with running a bot on a server and it uses Web3 to talk to my solidity contracts via infura.

Given the latency of a bot running in location X and the infura API being based in location Y, I was wondering if it would make sense to spin up my own ethereum node and run my bot on the same server and skip the whole infura step. Is this possible and would it provide any advantage?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it would reduce latency and help you in getting your transactions faster to the blockchain. But in reality in 99% of use cases latency doesn't make much difference, as long as it's not anything major (like being offline for some periods).

For Ethereum, what matters the most is *gas price*. So even if you gain 10ms in having a better latency the difference doesn't make any difference - using a slightly higher gas price does.